# multidex app gets ZipException: duplicate entry for junit, trying to run instrumented test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, junit

Trying to run instrumented test, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
    java.util.zip.ZipException:
        duplicate entry:
            org/junit/ClassRule.class
```

But sometimes `duplicate entry` is:

```
        duplicate entry:
            junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class
```

Which is obviously true: `Control-N` -> typing `ClassRule` shows:

1. `C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\a6c32b40bf3d76eca54e3c601e5d1470c86fcdfa\junit-4.12-sources.jar!\org\junit\ClassRule.java`
2. `C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit-dep\4.10\64417b3bafdecd366afa514bd5beeae6c1f85ece\junit-dep-4.10.jar!\org\junit\ClassRule.class`
   (Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 49.0 (Java 5.0)

Searching `ActiveTestSuite` gives 3 results, all in `C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\`

Is there a way to see the dependencies graph? I commented all `junit` related from the `app/build.gradle`'s dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    /// <Dagger>
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
    /// </Dagger>

    // ------ JSON ... ------
    testCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
    testCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4'
    // ------ ... JSON end ------
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'

    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    //androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'){
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    //<Floating Buttons>
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    //</Floating Buttons>
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

Comment: try this, add in to gradle.. configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

Comment: @WaqarYounis, I have this: `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0', 'junit:junit:4.12' }` (I added the `junit` just now). But the issue remains: `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class`

Comment: try this compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0

Comment: Dependency graph for module named "app" - gradlew app:dependencies. Also, this error is common if one of dependencies added junit by copy-pasting it (or added to libs folder as jar) in project, without changing junit's package. In such case dependency is unmanaged, hence gradle's resolution strategy does not work

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov, there is no way to find which library is the offensive?

Comment: start by class usages to find out all potential candidates, then examine their dependency trees - if lib/jar contains class, but does not expose it in gradle's dependency tree - you've found one

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov, I've been looking for a long while, finding nothing. Please note however that it only happens when I try to run an instrumented test, When issuing normal debug it works fine. Maybe it could hint something?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add below line to our dependencies list:

```
 testCompile "junit:junit:4.12'
```

Then, force this version of Junit dependency on the entire project by adding below block in our `app/build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This will solve all your dependency conflicts.

For more information:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: I have this: `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0', 'junit:junit:4.12' }` (I added the `junit` thanks to your answer). But the issue remains: `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class`

Comment: Hi @Tar, I just created project adding all dependencies posted in question and gradle build works in my case.

Comment: [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/droidwala/bbbce2887418f1beadc1be8166d122f7)          [app/build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/droidwala/9188f4c4228b96b22ebc96d1f2c84c90)

Comment: Are you sure you aren't importing any libraries by adding jars in your `libs/` folder in the project,correct?

Comment: I've been looking for a long while, finding nothing. Please note however that it only happens when I try to run an instrumented test, When issuing normal debug it works fine. Maybe it could hint something?

Comment: All you could do now is find out which library you import from `libs/` folder contains that `ActiveTestSuite.class`..And in case it is open-source project feel free to post github link.

Comment: Is it possible for you to tell us the jars you add to your project `libs/` folder? So, that i could add those locally and see which one causes the above conflict.